# importing CSS into a HTML does not work

Tags: html, css, import, styles

I am trying to @import CSS file into an HTML but it does not work. I did try linking path, It is not working either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Lesson</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style rel="stylesheet">
@import url("U5.css");
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="assets/script/U5.js" ></script>

</body>
```

But this format seems working as "http:....." ;

[U5-LättJS](http://127.0.0.1:54149/assets/pages/U5-JS.html)

```
href="http://127.0.0.1:54149/assets/pages/U5-JS.html"
```

Can I convert path to http so it can work? Thank you.

[click for validated code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBhxa.jpg)

Comment: why don't you just use the html tag designed for this? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="U5.css">`

Comment: I did @BalázsVarga but it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

If your CSS file is in the same directory use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./U5.css">
```

If this HTML file is at the root use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/pages/U5.css">
```

Use https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_link.asp for more information on linking to external style sheets

Answer (score 0):

Docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Lesson</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
   @import url("./FILE.css");
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="assets/script/U5.js" ></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

YESSSSSS!! I finally found how to do that. i just copied HTML path and wrote it as style path. Example for HTML;

```
href="http://127.0.0.1:54149/assets/pages/U5-JS.html"
```

so this is the style tag after change;

```
href=''http://127.0.0.1:54149/assets/style/U5.css''
```

So it perfectly works. I still do not know what was wrong. 
Thanks again all efford guys, i appreciated.